# Extremely low values from NumPy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, precision

I am attempting to do a few different operations in Numpy (`mean` and `interp`), and with both operations I am getting the result `2.77555756156e-17` at various times, usually when I'm expecting a zero. <strike>Even attempting to filter these out with `array[array < 0.0] = 0.0` fails to remove the values.</strike>

I assume there's some sort of underlying data type or environment error that's causing this. The data should all be float.

Edit: It's been helpfully pointed out that I was only filtering out the values of -2.77555756156e-17 but still seeing positive 2.77555756156e-17. The crux of the question is **what might be causing these wacky values** to appear when doing simple functions like interpolating values between 0-10 and taking a mean of floats in the same range, and how can I avoid it without having to explicitly filter the arrays after every statement.

Comment: Have you tried filtering this way: `array[array < 1e-16] = 0.0`. Your filtering function won't work because the values are not less than 0

Comment: probably floating point arithmetic issues. Can use `numpy.isclose()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're running into numerical precision, which is a huge topic in numerical computing; when you do any computation with floating point numbers, you run the risk of running into tiny values like the one you've posted here. What's happening is that your calculations are resulting in values that can't quite be expressed with floating-point numbers.

Floating-point numbers are expressed with a fixed amount of information (in Python, this amount defaults to 64 bits). You can read more about how that information is encoded on the very good [Floating point Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point). In short, some calculation that you're performing in the process of computing your mean produces an intermediate value that cannot be precisely expressed.

This isn't a property of numpy (and it's not even really a property of Python); it's really a property of the computer itself. You can see this is normal Python by playing around in the repl:

```
>>> repr(3.0)
'3.0'
>>> repr(3.0 + 1e-10)
'3.0000000001'
>>> repr(3.0 + 1e-18)
'3.0'
```

For the last result, you would expect `3.000000000000000001`, but that number can't be expressed in a 64-bit floating point number, so the computer uses the closest approximation, which in this case is just `3.0`. If you were trying to average the following list of numbers:

```
[3., -3., 1e-18]
```

Depending on the order in which you summed them, you could get `1e-18 / 3.`, which is the "correct" answer, or zero. You're in a slightly stranger situation; two numbers that you expected to cancel didn't quite cancel out.

This is just a fact of life when you're dealing with floating point mathematics. The common way of working around it is to eschew the equals sign entirely and to only perform "numerically tolerant comparison", which means equality-with-a-bound. So this check:

```
a == b
```

Would become this check:

```
abs(a - b) < TOLERANCE
```

For some tolerance amount. The tolerance depends on what you know about your inputs and the precision of your computer; if you're using a 64-bit machine, you want this to be at least `1e-10` times the largest amount you'll be working with. For example, if the biggest input you'll be working with is around 100, it's reasonable to use a tolerance of `1e-8`.

Answer (score 1):

You can round your values to 15 digits:

```
a = a.round(15)
```

Now the array `a` should show you `0.0` values.

Example:

```
>>> a = np.array([2.77555756156e-17])
>>> a.round(15)
array([ 0.])
```

Answer (score 1):

This is most likely the result of floating point arithmetic errors. For instance:

```
In [3]: 0.1 + 0.2 - 0.3
Out[3]: 5.551115123125783e-17
```

Not what you would expect? Numpy has a built in `isclose()` method that can deal with these things. Also, you can see the machine precision with

```
eps = np.finfo(np.float).eps
```

So, perhaps something like this could work too:

```
a = np.array([[-1e-17, 1.0], [1e-16, 1.0]])
a[np.abs(a) <= eps] = 0.0
```